# Delete tab at the beginning of the line in navigation mode

Tags: vim

Once under naviation mode, when the prompt is moved to the beginning of a line (for example, by a) that is started with a tab, the prompt will be located immediated after the tab. to delete that tab, one has to step in to insert mode (by i) then delete the tab (by backspace).

I am wondering how to delete the tab without changing modes?

Answer (score 1):

got the solution. at the navigation mode, using command:

```
0dl
```

or even simpler

```
0x
```

Answer (score 0):

In normal mode, you don't need to move the cursor to remove a leading tab, just use `<<`.

Comment: that is equivalent to **0x**

Comment: No. First because `<<` doesn't move the cursor, second because indentation can be done with tabs (`0x`, fine) or spaces (`0xxx`, not fine). Also `<C-d>` and `<C-t>` in insert mode.